# Strcat initialized value

Tags: c

I have code like this:

```
char *all_arguments = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*argc);

for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    strcat(all_arguments, argv[i]);
}
```

valgrind output:

```
==20425== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20425==    at 0x4C30C0A: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20425==    by 0x40065B: main (main.c:15)
```

What is wrong? I know that I should initialize all_arguments, but when I do "all_arguments = NULL;" I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: *You forgot to allocate memory for each argument.*

Comment: Need `*all_arguments = 0;` before for-loop.

Comment: And `argc` is the number of arguments, not their total length. So your `all_arguments` buffer is too small.

Comment: Just go with char all_arguments[1024]={0};

Comment: @MartinJames NO! the length of all arguments is **not** in general limited to 1024 characters, and that's how you code unnecessary bugs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller as distinct from the OP's code?  OK, char all_arguments[65536]={0};

Comment: @MartinJames just because OP's code doesn't work it's not ok to teach OP broken-by-design coding practices. No, 64kB isn't the maximum size for all arguments, either, on my machine (that is actually an adjustable size, and it's *pretty large*, so I'm *pretty sure* you don't want to reserve that much memory just too be lazy when `strcat`ing). Stop trying to solve this with magic constants, that's bad practice, and it's the stuff that people abuse for buffer overflows. The coding practice you show is security-wise the stuff of which nightmares are made.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, fine:  Now you wil lhave to teach the OP about malloc/realloc or some other parsing/storage technique.  May take some time. strncat() may be easiest.

Comment: @MartinJames no, I don't have to. See the accepted's answer second part: just count the length of all the argument strings, add them up, malloc and be done. There's no magic here. What you propose is really just bad practice that most people agree should simply not be followed.

Comment: This isn't what you are asking about, but I feel it worth mentioning that repeated use of strcat like this is a textbook example of the inefficient Schlemiel The Painter algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argc` holds number of parameters received to function `main` I assume.

So, before you copy new memory, simply realloc (extend) your memory for next entry.

```
char * all_parameters = malloc(1);

*all_parameters = 0; //Create valid string
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    //Extend to new size
    all_parameters = realloc(all_parameters, strlen(all_parameters) + 1 + strlen(argv[i]);
    //Copy together
    strcat(all_parameters, argv[i]);
}
```

Another option is to sum all lengths first and then use malloc only once.

```
int total_sum=0; // remember to initialize variable 
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    total_sum += strlen(argv[i]);
}

char * all_parameters = malloc(total_sum + 1);
*all_parameters = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    strcat(all_parameters, argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: @MarcusMüller we are not talking about worst/best, we are talking how to solve. Better would be to sum all lengths first, but it doesn't mean it is wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's easy to understand though, which I think is a plus.

Comment: Instead, you should have just added up all the `strlen(argv[i])`, `malloc`'ed all_parameters once (never had realloced) and then `strcat`ed all together. I don't think it's easy to understand (took me quite a while), but "easy" might be very relative to your expectations. Notice that it can be very expensive to `realloc`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller that's what I just said.

Comment: jep, we wrote our comments the at the same time. You got my upvote!

Comment: thanks guys! But tell me, which solution will be better? I want to know it for my knowledge.

Comment: @arhu second one.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1) You don't allocate enough memory for `all_arguments`. Even if each argument is only a single character, you still don't have space for the string terminator. And presumably, at least some of the arguments are larger.

2) Since `all_arguments` is not a string when it's first allocated, you can't pass it to `strcat`. The arguments to `strcat` must *both* be strings. The first time you call `strcat`, `all_arguments` is not valid string.